# Changing the className of a button based on state isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to change the CSS of a button based on whether or not it's active in state. For some reason, the className is not showing up in my HTML even though I am assigning it the value of the ternary conditional.

```
  var [isActive] = useState(false);
  var [btn_class] = useState('');

  const addOrRemove = (array, value) => {
    var index = array.indexOf(value);

    if (index === -1) {
      array.push(value);
      isActive = !isActive;
    } else {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      isActive = !isActive;
    }
    btn_class = isActive ? 'noBackground' : 'background';
  };

   <div>
            <Button
              onClick={e => addOrRemove(formData.interests, e.target.value)}
              value="Front-End Engineering"
              className={btn_class}
            >
              Front-End Engineering
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={e => addOrRemove(formData.interests, e.target.value)}
              value="Back-End Engineering"
              className={btn_class}
            >
              Back-End Engineering
            </Button>
          </div>
```

I'm looking for something exactly like this, but that approach isn't working.

https://jsfiddle.net/tkkqx2y2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the state for each button, like so:

```
var [frontend, setFrontend] = useState({
  isActive: true
});
var [backend, setBackend] = useState({
  isActive: true
});
```

and then set it onClick:

```
<div>
  <Button
    onClick={e => {
      setFrontend({ ...frontend, isActive: !frontend.isActive });
      addOrRemove(formData.interests, e.target.value);
    }}
    value="Front-End Engineering"
    className={frontend.isActive ? "noBackground" : "background"}
  >
    Front-End Engineering
  </Button>
  <Button
    onClick={e => {
      setBackend({ ...backend, isActive: !backend.isActive });
      addOrRemove(formData.interests, e.target.value);
    }}
    value="Back-End Engineering"
    className={backend.isActive ? "noBackground" : "background"}
  >
    Back-End Engineering
  </Button>
</div>
```

You probably can refactor the above based on the rest of your code, but the main idea is that you'll have to keep at least two states (it can be in the same `useState`, like `{first: true, second: true}`, one for each button.

You cannot have a shared state, otherwise when you change on one button it will change the other because they'll be using the exact same state.

You'll have to see how to structure your state in your particular app.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), you need a setter function to change the state.

Your state declarations would look like: `const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);` and in your addOrRemove function, call `setIsActive(!isActive);`

Comment: this worked, but now I just realized that when I click on one button, they ALL turn the same color. I need them to be independent of each other

Comment: Well, since btn_class is used for both buttons, they will have the same class. Luis's answer is a good example of how to seperate the state for those buttons.